# css @media запросы, как назначить стиль по умолчанию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

как указать стиль который будет работать, если не подошел ни один из предыдущих?
должно работать на новых браузерах хром/опера/фаирфокс  на андроид и виндовс

```
@media (orientation: landscape),(min-width: 420px){111}
@media (orientation: portrait),(max-width: 419px){222}
```

в какой то ситуации это не работает, мне нужно всегда включать 111 если не выбран 222

Comment: Что бы стиль сработал если не сработали предыдущие, то подключить его последним. А то что должен работать на "новых" браузерах - так это зависит от свойств которые вы хотите использовать.

Comment: с какими параметрами?

Comment: @NormalArs В чем проблема написать _@media (orientation: landscape),(max-width: 419px){111}_?

Answer (score 2):

Стили, написанные вне медиа-запроса, сработают везде, если не переопределятся медиа-запросом. Вам подойдет вот так:

```
111
@media (orientation: portrait),(max-width: 419px){222}
```

везде, где не 222 сработает 111

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто понимать, что стили применяются последовательно. Если какие-то не подошли, то применяются те что выше. Вплоть до дефолтных в браузере. В вашем случае, идет разделение на landscape и portrait. Вот и делайте две ветки, в одной стили для landscape, в другой для portrait.

```
...
@media (orientation: landscape),(min-width: 420px){111}
@media (orientation: landscape),(max-width: 419px){111}
@media (orientation: portrait),(min-width: 420px){222}
@media (orientation: portrait),(max-width: 419px){222}
...
```

В таком духе например.